# Javascript Runtime Error Involving Value Not Written in Code

Tags: javascript, error-handling, runtime-error

I am using App Lab on Code.org, which utilizes JavaScript commands; however, they have their own UI controls. Therefore, the code will contain commands such as onEvent() and setText(), etc. etc. These are all acceptable.

I am attempting to make a code for the Spherical Law of Cosines that calculates the distance between four different locations, but I am getting a runtime error message stating this: "Line: 171: Oops, we can’t figure out what -0.9208185005422157 is - perhaps you meant the string “-0.9208185005422157” with quotes? If this is meant to be a variable, make sure you declared a variable: var -0.9208185005422157."

The line in reference is as follows:

```
N = Math.acos((((((Math.abs(Math.cos(a)))*(Math.PI/180))*(Math.abs((Math.cos(b)(Math.PI/180))))+(((Math.abs(Math.sin(a)*(Math.PI/180)))+((Math.abs(Math.sin(b)*(Math.PI/180)))))*(((Math.abs(Math.cos(n))*(Math.PI/180)))))))));
```

Basically, I'm trying to find the value of the angle between two locations using the Spherical Law of Cosines, so I converted all of my values to degrees.

What would cause the error to log a random value in that line that I did not write?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing a *

```
Math.cos(b)(Math.PI/180)
```

should be

```
Math.cos(b)*(Math.PI/180)
```

Comment: Thank you! That was such a simple fix for how much I've tested it.

Comment: You are welcome! can you please mark the question as answered?